# Logical Connectives but 5 statements instead of 3

Tags: logical-deduction

Assume that each one of the numbered statements are individually true. Each of the two choices consists of a subset of these statements. Choose the subset as your answer where the statements therein are logically consistent among themselves.

1. Mangoes are not oranges.
2. Grapes are apples.
3. Apples are mangoes.
4. Mangoes are bananas.
5. Bananas are oranges.
6. Oranges are grapes.
7. Bananas are not apples.

Options: (A) 2, 3, 4, 5, 6; (B) 1, 4, 2, 6, 7

Answer:

> Option (B)

Why is the other option not the correct answer?

Note: I had asked similar question in [Logical Connection Problems: which sets of statements are logically consistent?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116540/logical-connection-problems-which-sets-of-statements-are-logically-consistent?noredirect=1#comment325981_116540)
also but since SQLnoob had cleared major part of the doubt there so question was quite redundant and to be fair to SQLnoob, I did not edit my question. Only doubt mentioned here remains. It wasn't coming into the limelight on the other post.

**Edit:** I've got the general idea that many people here think that option A is consistent and the answer given saying only option B is incorrect.

I can't delete this question as I have an answer already and neither can I edit this post further as then it won't be solving it's purpose (of doubt clearance) so kindly refrain from further downvoting the post and if anyone has different opinion from the general idea, please leave an answer or a comment, I'll be glad to engage.

If you have a differing opinion, you might be interested in hearing one such opinion that I didn't get how it works though:

> In option (A) all statements are affirmative and universal statements, where each term is mentioned exactly twice but distributed exactly once. So, they are not consistent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logical Connection Problems: which sets of statements are logically consistent?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116540/logical-connection-problems-which-sets-of-statements-are-logically-consistent)

Comment: @Auribouros please read my question till the end.

Comment: I did, yet it seems like making another post for the unanswered parts of the last one is still redundant

Comment: @Auribouros I would have to edit my post to look same as here so as to pin point my leftover doubts, but then I have received 2 answers there already, they would seem as if they're talking about something else, which I didn't want to do. I asked some people with high reputation if I should make another post or not, I got no answer, so I went with my gut feelings.

Comment: As pointed out elsewhere, I think your questions are either missing a lot of source-specific context, or are just from a bad source. We're not really going to be able to make sense of whatever nonstandard logic the text is using that would indicate, for example, that A is not a correct answer for question 1.

Comment: @SQLnoob you've given the best answer as of yet, so could you please give last attempt at the above mentioned question? Please note: option B is correct via 4,7,2,6,1 route and regarding option A I was told that since each term is mentioned exactly twice but distributed exactly once, so it is not consistent, though I don't get why so.

Comment: I have edited my question please re-consider your downvotes.

Comment: All seven of these statements are logically consistent, with the conclusion that no instances of these five fruit types exist.

Comment: To be frank, your question doesn't seem to make sense. Option A is correct, so the question "why isn't option A correct?" is meaningless. (Of course, option B is correct as well.)

Comment: @InanimateBeing I'm not sure what more I can add to the conversation. Either you're misrepresenting what the textbook is asking, or the textbook is wrong. Without a copy of the textbook, no one here can tell you which of those is the case, unfortunately. As it stands, it seems like a nonsensical question.

Comment: Whoever told you that "since each term is mentioned exactly twice but distributed exactly once, it is not consistent" is wrong.

Comment: The only bit of sense I can get from this is that in set A none of the statements can be deduced from the others.  But in set B statement 1 can be deduced from the others.  But, well, that is not what I call logical consistency.

Comment: Wow! Finally! Nice Observation, despite multiple reads I was still overlooking this. Thanks a lot for your answer. A lot of importance has been given in these type of questions where a circular logic is created via last conclusion from 4 statements matching the 5th statement to finally consider it as a valid option. So your answer fits perfectly well. Also, I agree both the options are logically consistent and the question setter should have not framed it that way, maybe focused upon the  circular conclusion instead.

Comment: A request, @FlorianF could you please up vote the question so I can get the upvote privilege back?

Comment: I voted to delete this post.  It might restore your reputation.  Not sure.

Comment: Also, I can now say that the question/doubt has been put to rest. @FlorianF so if you wish, then I can mark my problem as solved basis your answer

Comment: @FlorianF I'm not sure either but please give it a try.

Comment: Thanking you again @FlorianF

Comment: Just making sure, you're aware that FlorianF's comment was just a guess, right? You seem to think that your question has been answered with certainty, and that makes me think that either you know some important details that we don't, or you have misunderstood FlorianF's comment.

Comment: @TannerSwett Below FlorianF's comment I have mentioned the reason why it seems correct and convincing to me. Something worth mentioning , since you asked, is that as this is an international community so maybe certain rules that I follow to solve such questions aren't popular/accepted. For example, here most believe that even if all 5 statements are negative, they can be logically consistent due to empty set but such a possibility isn't allowed in my region. This confusion was present throughout and earned me downvotes too. It can be seen in the discussion that happened in link in my question

Comment: It's true that definitions and conventions differ from textbook to textbook, but I would be very, very surprised if any textbook ever used the phrase "not consistent" to mean "none of the statements can be deduced from the others." That said, I admit that I have been surprised before, and that I haven't seen your textbook, so maybe it really does say that. Maybe it would be a good idea to go back and look at how your textbook defines the word "consistent." If it does have a very unusual definition of "consistent," that probably explains why people had difficulty understanding your question.

Comment: @TannerSwett nicely said. Also, the issue is that "consistent" might have unusual definition here, but its meaning is taken for granted to such an extent that I just looked at my textbook and nowhere "consistent" is defined as if the general meaning is accepted at a societal level, which surprisingly, despite globalization of even exams, is still not popular apparently as evidenced from discussions here. So, actual solution lies in reading books of foreign authors or GMAT type but given that majority people engaging here weren't from a specific region & thus localized meaning of "consistent".

Answer (score 2):

[EDITED to add:] Since I posted this InanimateBeing has edited the question in a way that makes parts of it no longer make much sense. What's now in InanimateBeing's question is what was originally Q2, and there was originally also a "hint" for that question that had allegedly been supplied and which InanimateBeing was asking about.

I think the meaning of the questions is rather unclear, and whether option A in Q1 is an acceptable answer depends on interpretation.

Option A (2,3,4,5,6) gives us a circular chain like this: As are Bs, Bs are Cs, Cs are Ds, Ds are Es, Es are As. These are obviously all consistent with one another if we allow everything to be the same (so e.g. all those fruit names are just code for some single type of thing), and they are not consistent if we assume that different words have to denote *different* sets of things.

The fact that the question doesn't make this clearer is a deficiency in the question.

The hint for Q2 is just incorrect. If I say e.g. "Xs are not Ps", "Ys are not Qs" and "Zs are not Rs" then I have made an odd number of negative statements but they are clearly consistent with one another. Likewise if I say "Some As are not Bs", "Some Bs are not Cs", and "Some Cs are not Ds".

There isn't even an inconsistency when you have a cycle like this: "Some As are not Bs", "Some Bs are not Cs", "Some Cs are not As". (Imagine that A,B,C denote *disjoint* sets of things: actual literal apples, oranges and grapes, for instance.) The same applies if we have "No As are Bs", "No Bs are Cs", and "No Cs are As".

And in fact option A in Q2, which they say is inconsistent, is perfectly consistent (so long as we ignore the actual meanings of the words they are using). Suppose there are 6 things. 1 is red and green. 2 is orange. 3 is green. 4 is blue. 5 is violet. 6 is orange and violet. Then: "Some violets are not blue" is true (5 and 6 are both violet-but-not-blue). "No orange is red" is true (2 is the only orange thing and it isn't red). "Some oranges are violets" is true (6 is orange and is also violet). "Every red is green" is true (1 is the only red thing, and it is also green). "No green is blue" is true (1 and 3 are the only green things, and they are not blue).

I think that whoever wrote the things you're using was incompetent and you should not be taking their advice.

Comment: would you agree with this that had there been only 1 negative statement in among the 5 statements then no conclusion can be drawn?

Comment: If one statement were "some apples are oranges" and another were "no apples are oranges" then there would be a contradiction from just those, so no.

Comment: The reason one negative statement doesn't works is that since all other are positive statements so we can't end up with a negative statement with respect to circular logic and similarly, using a negative statement can never lead us to a positive conclusion in same regards (circular logic).

Comment: My apologies for the inconvenience caused